# Why demons take birth ? And they do not vanished as they do anything wrong?

Tags: gods, karma

God knows everything like present , future and past than why did they not vanish the demons as they take birth. These demons upset the earth by their act like killing , raping , corruption etc.

From my point of view If any person doing any wrongful act than he/she should die immediately. Than why god do not give punishment at the same time when any thing become wrong

Comment: It is because of Past good deeds they are enjoying. Moreover, not all demons are bad, demons also practice asceticism, perform pooja, devote themselves to God.

Comment: Today's humans are more cruel than past Demons himself. Did humans vanish? And not all demons are cruel, have your forgot about Prahlad, King bali, Vibhishan and so on. There are many demons who were pure soul.

Comment: @Rishabh ... Yes i talking  about today demons , we are more cruel than our ancestor demons..

Comment: Oh didn't read full question earlier, my apologies. I will let you know about my views on this. Right now little busy.